# Mathematical functions in functional programming

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have just started learning clojure.As it belongs to a category of functional programming,as a first step i am figuring out how it is different from imperative programming. So i have learnt from wikipedia and other sources some raw knowledge.So I am pretty confused with this line saying

There are functions in imperative programming and mathematical functions in functional programming .Here what do mathematical functions exactly mean?How is it different from functions.

Consider mathematically a function f(x)=X^2+X+1
In terms of object oreiented programming we write a function which accepts an argument x and returns the calculated value.I believe the same is the case with functional programming.Then what does it mean by

```
    Treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions 
and avoids changing-state and mutable data.
```

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 3):

By mathematical function it is meant a function that always returns the same value when called with the same inputs. The following, for example, is not a mathematical function:

```
a = 0
def f(x):
  a += 1
  return x + a
```

Because, of course, if you call it multiple times with the same `x` you will get back different values. This happens because `f` increments `a`, this is what is called *side effect* and is what should be avoided in functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. You might want to read up on:

- [Programming Paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms)
- [Referential Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)

In this case here, "mathematical functions" refers to the property of "not causing side-effects" e.g. printing to the display, changing variables or sending packets over the network. Functions in OO-languages do usually modify state (they change the values of the corresponding object instance), whereas in functional languages, they don't.

An example of a mathematical function (fullfills referential transparency, e.g. given the same input, it returns the same output):

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

An example of two non-mathematical functions (`__init__` and `increment`). These are still functions, but they are "changing" things e.g. the variable `current_count`):

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_count = 0

    def increment():
        self.current_count += 1
```